# Is it possible to have %n newlines in strings.xml format strings with parameters?

Tags: java, android, string, string-formatting, format-string

I'm having an issue with having a `%n` newline in an android format string.

This is the intended output:

```
Address Line 1
City, State
```

So I created a format string like this:

```
%s%n%s, %s
```

But I got this error:

> Error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?

My string is formatted, so that second solution doesn't seem to make sense, so I made the `%s`'s positional:

```
%1$s%n%2$s, %3$s
```

But I still got the same error.

So I tried making the `%n` positional too, just to see if that'd fix the issue:

```
%1$s%4$n%2$s, %3$s
```

And then I got a runtime error (!!!) by `java.util.Formatter`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.app, PID: 27843
        java.util.IllegalFormatFlagsException: %n doesn't take an argument
            at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.checkFlags(Formatter.java:1373)
            at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1442)
            at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1081)
            at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
            at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
            at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1554)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:431)
            ... // omitting project specific files
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**How can have a `%n` newline in a strings.xml format string with other format parameters? Is it possible? If not, what's the best way to display a newline?**

Android documentation or api guide references would be appreciated.

Comment: @Distwo `\n` works, but I'd prefer to use `%n` in a format string, so I've updated my question to ask if there's any way to use `%n`, and if not what's the best way to do a newline. Perhaps the answer is it is impossible and `\n` is the best solution.

Comment: How about that: `%1$s%2$n%3$s, %4$s`

Comment: Nevermind... Doesn't work.

Comment: @Distwo yeah unfortunately it seems like the `Formatter` class doesn't accept `%n` with an argument but Android doesn't accept `%n` without an argument...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a bug.

Look at the AAPT sources -- specifically at the [hasSubstitutionErrors method](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/4b1a8f46d6ec55796bf77fd8921a5a242a219278/tools/aapt/XMLNode.cpp#L99). It counts the number of arguments in the string to check if they should be positional. It makes sure to skip the literal percent sign (`%%`) but it doesn't skip the platform-specific newline symbol (`%n`).

I have raised this problem in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231846).

At this point I don't see a solution other than using `\n`.

**EDIT**: the issue has been marked as fixed in the tracker.